# EditorJS, php и запись в БД

Tags: javascript, php

Решил вот использовать визуальный редактор https://editorjs.io Но что-то никак не пойму как получить данные с этого редактора и записать в БД.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать?

Comment: Прочтите по нему документацию, там все хорошо описано

Comment: @Ghost, https://github.com/editor-js/editorjs-php но не понял как использовать.

Comment: Никак, это просто пример бека

Comment: @Ghos, тогда где конкретно читать?

Comment: О чем кокретно? Как данные проверить? Как отправить?

Comment: @Ghos, и как проверить и как отправить.

Comment: В задачи компанента не входит отправка данных - только ввод, из докуметации тело состоит из блоков, вам для каждого типа блока нужно сделать валидцию

Comment: Вот здесь все есть что нужно https://editorjs.io/api

Comment: @Ghost, проще наверное найти другой визуальный редактор. Максимум что получилось сделать так это получить ошибку "Field `blocks` is missing" при использовании https://github.com/editor-js/editorjs-php

Comment: Хороший редактор, просто вам надо разобраться в нем, https://github.com/editor-js/editorjs-php/blob/21f355a7c2be2800a99e6e8a470941fa33a96cc4/EditorJS/EditorJS.php#L77

Comment: @Ghost, да что-то не удается разобраться...

Comment: @vitagame Просто перегоните то, что пришло от редактора через json_decode и работайте с массивом данных как угодно. И не нужно эту библиотеку для PHP даже использовать.

А так, редактор очень даже годный. Уж получше будет, чем всякие TinyMCE или CKeditor, которые тупо html сырой отдают, над которым нужно плясать с бубном...

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, json_decode выдает пустоту. Возможно не правильно данные отправляю https://yadi.sk/d/Dm_GhmwXOymnhw

Comment: @vitagame Так данные не сохраняются из метода html(). Почитайте это: https://editorjs.io/saving-data

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, что-то не пойму как тогда передавать данные.

Comment: @vitagame В документации всё хорошо расписано. Создаёте экземпляр для элемента с id, по клику вызываете для экземпляра метод save(), он возвращает готовые данные. Дальше передаёте их по ajax куда хотите. В ссылке выше есть же код... Просто прочитайте хорошо документацию и всё, там всего из нужного 3 первых страницы.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, все-таки придется TinyMCE использовать т.к. ничего не получается.

Comment: @vitagame Не получается прочитать? https://codepen.io/erriourru/pen/GRJxPrO

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, спасибо, осталось разобраться как теперь встроить в мой ajax.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, с этим разобрался. Осталось разобраться как все это дело записать в БД.